# -bash: class-dump: command not found

Tags: macos

I have downloaded the class-dump from http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/.
And I open class-dump with Terminal,but the result is following:

```
Last login: Fri Apr 22 16:46:57 on ttys000  
yu-brooks-imac:~ yubrook$ /Users/yubrook/Desktop/class-dump ; exit;  
class-dump 3.3.3 (64 bit)  
Usage: class-dump [options] \<mach-o-file> 

  where options are:
        -a             show instance variable offsets
        -A             show implementation addresses
        --arch <arch>  choose a specific architecture from a universal binary (ppc, ppc64, i386, x86_64)
        -C <regex>     only display classes matching regular expression
        -f <str>       find string in method name
        -H             generate header files in current directory, or directory specified with -o
        -I             sort classes, categories, and protocols by inheritance (overrides -s)
        -o <dir>       output directory used for -H
        -r             recursively expand frameworks and fixed VM shared libraries
        -s             sort classes and categories by name
        -S             sort methods by name
        -t             suppress header in output, for testing
        --list-arches  list the arches in the file, then exit
        --sdk-root     specify the SDK root path (full path, or 4.1, 4.0, 3.2, 10.6, 10.5, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 3.1)
logout

[Process completed]
```

I don't understand how to run the class-dump. Please help me.

I tap the class-dump on the command line,the result is:

> yu-brooks-imac:Desktop yubrook$ class-dump
> -bash: class-dump: command not found

Answer (score 1):

By installing class-dump manually and downloading the class-dump in using this [Steve Nygard](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/). Then copy the class-dump file to the following location "/usr/local/bin". after this everything will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

This is because the operating system does not recognize the current folder path.
Navigate to the current folder that you have downloaded the code. Run as follows:

```
./class-dump
```